# advance search in one field. php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have FullName field and I want to do an advance search on it.
For example:

The name was recorded is: "Mike Jone Terbiani"

If I use **LIKE** then:

- if the INPUT is mike it will return true
- if the INPUT is mik it will return true
- if the INPUT is jone it will return true
- if the INPUT is mike jone it will return true
- if the INPUT is jone Terbiani it will return true

**BUT** if the INPUT is mike Terbiani it will return false

What's the way to make it true?
To make the following:

- if the INPUT is mike it will return true
- if the INPUT is Terbiani it will return true
- if the INPUT is mike Terbiani it will return true
- if the INPUT is ke Terbi it will return true because it's in order.
- if the INPUT is Terbiani mike it will return false because it's
  **NOT** in order.

Thanks

Comment: That'll be $100. **But seriously:** we are not your personal coding monkeys, stack overflow is a site to gain **help** on your problems because **your code doesn't work and you can't find the bug/issue** or **solve it**. If you actually attempted this issue, please supply the code otherwise refrain from posting questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replaces the spaces in the input with `%`, and put `%` around the whole thing, and use `LIKE`. So if the input is `ke Terbiani`, use:

```
$like = preg_replace('/\s+|^|$/', '%', $fullname);

$sql = "SELECT ... FROM table WHERE fullName LIKE '$like'"
```